# Change event not fire if change comes from antoher function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wrote validation for form input fields and everything works fine except address fields which are filled with Google's autocomplete function. I saw similar post where this event is not firing if the change comes from function rather than user, and I know I should use create and dispatch event but everything I tried to combine this into my code didn't worked, so if anyone can help.

I used this code for event creation for field which is filled with function:

```
el = document.getElementById('route');
ev = document.createEvent('Event');
ev.initEvent('change', true, false);
el.dispatchEvent(ev);
```

And this is my JQuery in which I need to catch new event:

```
$.each(obj, function(key){

$("#"+key+"").on("change blur", function(){

    //Check if empty
    if(this.value==''){
        if($(this).parent().hasClass("has-error")){
            return false;
        }else{if($(this).parent().hasClass("has-success")){
                $(this).parent().removeClass("has-success");
                $(this).parent().find('span#glyph-ok').remove();
            }else{//Check if already was wrong
                $(this).addClass('form-control');
                $(this).parent().addClass('has-error');
                $(this).parent().append('<span id="glyph-error" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>');
                $(this).parent().append('<div class="error-hint-empty alert alert alert-warning"><span class="warning-glyph glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span>You must input '+$("#"+key+"").parent().find('label').text()+'!</div>');
                if($(this).parent().hasClass("has-success")){
                        $(this).parent().removeClass("has-success");
                        $(this).parent().find('span#glyph-ok').remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        if($(this).parent().hasClass("has-success")){return false;}else{//Check if already was ok
        $(this).addClass('form-control');
        $(this).parent().addClass('has-success');
        $(this).parent().append('<span id="glyph-ok" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></span>');
        if($(this).parent().hasClass("has-error")){
                $(this).parent().removeClass("has-error");
                $(this).parent().find('span#glyph-error').remove();
                $(this).parent().find('span#text-error').remove();
                $(this).parent().find('div.error-hint-empty').remove();
            }
        }
    }//End if empty

    //Check patterns and types

});//End of events

});//End of each empty field notification
```

Comment: try `$('#route').change()` to fire the event

Comment: Rather than using $(this) repeatedly, consider storing it in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

The `change` event is not fired when you programmatically change the value of an element.  It is triggered with user interaction of the element, which doesn't happen via the JavaScript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change

If you want the event to be fired in your script you will need to trigger it manually with `$('route').change()`